# How to have an integrated workflow using Jupyter, PyCharm CE, and Github and maximize their features?

Tags: python, github, pycharm, data-science, jupyter

I've just begun my career transition to tech (Data Science) and want to create a smooth workflow using Jupyter, PyCharm, and Github, specifically maximizing the features of each platform.

For example, I run my Python code on Jupyter (.ipynb) but I cannot run the file on PyCharm CE. Likewise, I cannot run or edit .py files in Jupyter. What's the workaround, or is there a better way of doing this?

This is my first question here so please don't be too harsh. I'm looking forward to learning from all of you.

Comment: jupyter has a console mode. I test most of my SO answers in a ipython session. But any editor that has python highlighting works for editing scripts.

Comment: Thanks, since PyCharm has python highlighting, I'm now able to edit my code on it without having to go to Jupyter and edit. What are console mode and SO answers?